# FrameLayout.getLayoutParams causing app to close

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I'm loading an image into an `ImageView`.  The `ImageView` is contained in a `FrameLayout`. Loading the image works as expected but now I want to set the margins of the `FrameLayout` to match the size of the loaded image as I will be added other views into the `FrameLayout` as overlays to the image.

For doing this I've created a static method in a utility class which is different from the class that contains the `FrameLayout` and the `ImageView`.  When running the method in the `utilityclass` it dumps out of the app on the line shown in the code below which is trying to get the `LayoutParams` of the `FrameLayout`.

As I don't get an error message I'm finding it hard to understand what is wrong. Can anyone point me in the correct direction.

Code that handles the image loading as an Activity for result

```
case REQUEST_OPEN_GALLERY:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        getSelectedFileFromGallery(data);

         // This block is the new code to apply the layoutParams
          FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_Layout);
          ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_View);
          Utils.addMarginsToImageContainer(fLayout, iView);
          //End of the new block

          toggleViewStatus(ENABLE_OVERLAY_VIEWS); //Enable the text and overlay control
     }
break;
```

This block of code is the new method that is called and causes the crash\app closure.

```
public static void addMarginsToImageContainer(FrameLayout fLayout, ImageView iView){
        Integer imageWidth = iView.getWidth();
        Integer imageHeight = iView.getWidth();
        Integer frameWidth = fLayout.getWidth();
        Integer frameHeight = fLayout.getHeight();
        Integer widthDifference = frameWidth - imageWidth;
        Integer heightDifference = frameHeight - imageHeight;
        //Done TO DO: what happens here with no integer returns
        Integer widthMargin =  (int) Math.ceil(widthDifference / 2);
        Integer heightMargin = (int) Math.ceil(heightDifference /2);

        //TODO: The next line crashes the app
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams fLayoutLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fLayout.getLayoutParams();
        if (widthMargin > 0 && heightMargin > 0) {
            fLayoutLayoutParams.setMargins(widthMargin,heightMargin,widthMargin,heightMargin);
        }
        else if (widthMargin > 0 && heightMargin <= 0){
            fLayoutLayoutParams.setMargins(widthMargin,0,widthMargin,0);
        }
        else if (widthMargin <= 0 && heightMargin > 0){
            fLayoutLayoutParams.setMargins(0,heightMargin,0,heightMargin);
        }
        else{
            fLayoutLayoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        }
        fLayout.setLayoutParams(fLayoutLayoutParams);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if anyone needs any additional code sections but if so please let me know and I'll post them.  Any help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** - I've just realised that running the app as opposed to debugging on the handset has raised an error. The error is

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1,
>   data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/3377 flg=0x1
>   }} to activity myActivity java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Looking at this it may be relevant to note that the framelayout is contained in a RelativeLayout.  However, why the system is casting the framelayout params to relativelayout params I don't yet understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that this has actually been asked before now I've seen the actual error message (Added as an edit to original post).  I resolved the issue by changing the line

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams fLayoutLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

to use RelativeLayout Params instead e.g.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fLayoutLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

As to the reasons as to why you need the top level parent view's layout parameters as opposed to the layout parameters of the view that I'm actually trying to influence.  I think that is a question that has been better answered already and at this stage I don't fully understand it.

Comment: I love those moments when you're googling for an error and one person had the same error four years ago and bothered to document the solution they had themselves. Looks like the LayoutParams subclass is one that is compatible with the parent view, i.e. describes how the given view is to be laid out in its parent. Seems like one of those design choices that made perfect sense at the time but the designer now kicks himself every time he gets asked about it. :)

Comment: when is chatgpt going to learn this darn